# Jaxb: how to unmarshall xs:any XML-string part?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an application doing XML<->conversions using Jaxb and automatically generated classes with maven-jaxb2-plugin.

Someplace deep in my schema, I have the possibility to enter "ANY" xml.

Update: this better describes my schema. Some known XML wrapping a totally unknown part (the "any" part).

```
<xs:complexType name="MessageType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="XmlAnyPayload" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any namespace="##any"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="OtherElements">
        ....
</xs:sequence>
```

This maps (by jaxb) to a inner class like this.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public static class XmlAnyPayload {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected Object any;
```

When I unmarshall the entire structure, it is no problem. The "Object any" will render into a org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl. Now, I want to recreate the Java object manually and then go to XML. How do I take some random XML and put into the any (org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl) element to be able to build up the Java object?

Also, the next case is when I have this element as java, I want to unmarshall this very part (to be able to extract the XML string of this element). But this is not possible. I get an exception about root elements. But it is not possible to annotate ElementNSImpl.

```
unable to marshal type "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to handle these problems?

Comment: Thanks to good input into this domain, I managed to solve this. One way, I stuck with my Dom node. Just added some simple XML parsing to get the dom from string. The other way, I resorted to work with the XML in DOM space (XPATH wise), since it actually saved me some time and context switches. XPATH is actually really good to keep the code complexity down.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)` means in plain English something like:

> Dear JAXB! If you have a mapping for this element, please unmarshal it
>   into a Java object. If you don't know this element, just leave it as a
>   DOM element.

This is exactly what is happening in your case. So if you want to actually unmarshal the content of this lax any, provide JAXB context with a mapping for the element you wish to unmarshal. The easiest way to do this is to annotate your class with `@XmlRootElement`

```
@XmlRootElement(name="foo", namespace="urn:bar")
public class MyClass { ... }
```

Now when you create your JAXB context, add `MyClass` into it:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class, B.class, ..., MyClass.class);
```

In this case, if JAXB meets the `{urn:bar}foo` element in the place of that `xs:any`, it will know that this element is mapped onto `MyClass` and will try to unmarshal MyClass.

If you are creating JAXB context based on the package name (you probably do), you can still add you class (say, `com.acme.foo.MyClass`) to it. The easiest way is to create a `com/acme/foo/jaxb.index` resource:

```
com.acme.foo.MyClass
```

And the add your package name to the context path:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.dar.gee.schema:com.acme.foo");
```

There are other ways with `ObjectFactory` etc., but the trick with `jaxb.index` is probably the easiest one.

Alternatively, instead of unmarshalling everything in one run, you can leave the content of `xs:any` as DOM and unmarshal it into the target object in a second unmarshalling with anothe JAXB context (which know your `MyClass` class). Something like:

```
JAXBContext payloadContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
payloadContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal((Node) myPayload.getAny());
```

This approach is sometimes better, especially when you have a combination of container/payload schemas which are relatively independent. Depends on the case.

All said above applies to marshalling as well. It's all neatly bidirectional.

Comment: This answer was a life saver. Needless to say I upvoted it, I am just sorry I can't do it twice. An excellent explanation plus a good solution - thank you, lexicore!

Comment: @Quantum You're welcome. Saving lives just got a bit easier. :)

Comment: @lexicore So, if XmlAnyElement is set to false/omitted, it will leave it as a DOM object?

Comment: Not sure why, but I'm running into the same problem and nothing you or @Blaise-Doughan has mentioned is working.  My codes an EJB Web Service project on JBoss EAP 7 and the received WS argument has null for all the "Any" types.  Rather frustrating!

Comment: @JGlass Sorry to hear that but it is generally known to work.

Comment: No worries - someone, somewhere on google has got to have an answer!  I shall keep trying - my last resort is to just have a servlet that acts as a web service that can handle the raw XML but as you know, that may get messy.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the XSDs for this "any" part and generate classes for them as well.

Here is some more information:

http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_of__xs_any___.html

Edit: if your object you want to marshal doesn't have the @XmlRootElement annotation (see error message), then I think you have to wrap it with a JAXBElement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I will never know the exact content of this "any" message, nor I want to know. I just want to be able to handle it as a chunk.

Comment: The guide linked to gives some nice detail knowledge in this domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:any/>
```

requires some not intuitive stuff to be converted to java object. If you have no difference, try using

```
<element name="any" type="xs:anyType"/>
```