# JAXB2, how to partially validate against an XML Schema that includes an xsd:any element?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

Is it possible in JAXB to only validate, during the unmarshalling, up to an **xsd:any** element and drill no further?

The use case is that I have two XML Schema files, one defining the envelope (which includes at some point an **xsd:any** element) and another one defining the payload schema (for the **xsd:any** element). Since actually there can be many different types of payload - with more to come in the future - I've built my code to use two-step unmarshalling as suggested in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687588/jaxb-how-to-unmarshall-xsany-xml-string-part).

So I have a library that only unmarshalls and validates the envelope without looking at the payload. The thing is that using JAXB I can't figure a way to only  validate the envelope using the `setSchema` method of the `Unmarshaller`. The validation fails because it can't find the schema of the payload, but I can't add these schemas in the envelope-handling **jar** since the envelope is supposed to be agnostic of the payloads. So I am not able to implement the envelope-handling logic in its own library in a manner agnostic of the payloads.

A minimal, concrete example follows. When the code runs it fails with:

```
 [java] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 23; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'b:person'.
```

### envelope - A.XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
        xmlns               ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:a             ="http://www.example.org/A"
        targetNamespace ="http://www.example.org/A">
       <element name="someType" type="a:SomeType"></element>
        <complexType name="SomeType">
            <sequence>
                <any namespace="##other" processContents="strict"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
</schema>
```

### payload - B.XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns          ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:b        ="http://www.example.org/B"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/B"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <element name="person" type="b:PersonType"></element>
    <complexType name="PersonType">
        <sequence>
                <element name="firstName" type="string"/>
                <element name="lastName"  type="string"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </schema>
```

### XML instance - ab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:someType xmlns:a="http://www.example.org/A"
        xmlns:b="http://www.example.org/B"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/A A.xsd
                            http://www.example.org/B B.xsd">
        <b:person>
            <b:firstName>Mary</b:firstName>
            <b:lastName>Bones</b:lastName>
        </b:person>
</a:someType>
```

### JAXB code

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException, SAXException {
    final Schema SCHEMA_A = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(new File("A.xsd"));
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.a");
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    u.setSchema(SCHEMA_A);
    JAXBElement<SomeType> element = (JAXBElement<SomeType>) u.unmarshal( new FileInputStream( "ab.xml" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to achieve this kind of partial validation with JAXB. However using `javax.xml.validation.Validator` I was to validate the outer envelope and suppress the exception when the payload element is reached with a custom `org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler`. The solution is not satisfactory at all as it relies on a comparison of the exception message in order to suppress the exception (the `getColumnNumber` and `getLineNumber` methods of the `SAXParseException` class cannot be used as the exact line and column where the error occurs are not fixed XML instance documents).

I paste the code below, but like I said I don't like the message comparison suppression logic at all as I have to anticipate all possible **any** payload elements (since the element name appears in the message). Is there a better way?

```
class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException exc) {
        throw exc;
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exc) throws SAXParseException {
        if (exc.getMessage().equals("cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'b:person'."))
            ; // suppress
        else
            throw exc;
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exc) throws SAXParseException {
        throw exc;
    }
}

public class FooMain {


    public static void main (String args[]) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException, SAXException, IOException  {
        String xmlFileName = "ab.xml";
        final Schema SCHEMA_A = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(new File("A.xsd"));
        SAXSource source = new SAXSource(new InputSource(xmlFileName));
        Validator validator = SCHEMA_A.newValidator();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
        validator.validate(source);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.a");
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        // u.setSchema(SCHEMA_A); // not possible to partially validate using this method
        JAXBElement<SomeType> element = (JAXBElement<SomeType>) u.unmarshal( new FileInputStream( xmlFileName ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for
>   element 'b:person'.

This message says that any element is declared with `processContents="strict"` (which is default) in your schema. The validator is expected to process the content of any element but the element declaration `b:person` is missing.

There are two ways to handle the situation:

1. Make sure the set of schema provided to validator includes `b:person` element declaration - it is possible to provide more than one schema source to `SchemaFactory.newSchema`. Validator will validate the full XML in this case, including the contents of any elements.
2. OR - Relax content processing rules by specifying attribute `processContents="lax"` or `processContents="skip"` in you schema for any element declaration in order to perform partial validation as described at [XML Schema any Element](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_any.asp). Validator will NOT validate the full XML in this case, skipping the contents of any elements.