# Use Jaxb to unmarshall part of XML to an instance of org.jdom.Element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I'm working in a legacy product that heavily relies on version 1 of the org.jdom project (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom/1.1.3) and manually constructed XMLs but I would like to use Jaxb as much as possible instead. We're using Moxy as the Jaxb implementation.

So say that I have the following xml:

```
<foo bar="bar">
    <baz>
        <test value="something" />
    </baz>
</foo>
```

And because of legacy code using the baz element as an org.jdom.Element I would like to have Jaxb unmarshall the inner element "baz" to an org.jdom.Element but v in unmarshal is always an empty string ("") so baz becomes null.
I've created an example below where I try to use an XmlAdapter but I can't get it to work.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

    String fooString = "<foo bar=\"bar\"><baz><test value=\"something\" /></baz></foo>";
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
            .createContext(new Class<?>[] {Foo.class}, null);
    javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Foo foo = unmarshaller
            .unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(fooString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))), Foo.class)
            .getValue();

    System.out.println(foo);
  }

  @XmlRootElement
  private static final class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String bar;

    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ElementAdapter.class)
    public Element baz;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo [bar=" + bar + ", baz=" + baz + "]";
    }

  }

  private static final class ElementAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Element> {

    @Override
    public Element unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        Document document = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader(v));
        return document.getRootElement();
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Element v) throws Exception {
        return new XMLOutputter(org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat()).outputString(v);
    }

  }

}
```

Maybe I'm attacking this from the wrong angle. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would share a solution that worked for me.

Inspired by this post [Jaxb: how to unmarshall xs:any XML-string part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687588/jaxb-how-to-unmarshall-xsany-xml-string-part?rq=1) that mentions that Jaxb leaves anything it doesn't know how to map as DOM element when marked as @XmlAnyElement(lax = true) I ended up with an XmlAdapter using org.w3c.dom.Element as an intermediate class that Jaxb knows how to map to and from.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.output.DOMOutputter;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

    String fooString = "<foo bar=\"bar\"><baz><test value=\"something\" /></baz></foo>";
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
            .createContext(new Class<?>[] {Foo.class}, null);
    javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Foo foo = unmarshaller
            .unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(fooString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))), Foo.class)
            .getValue();

    System.out.println(foo);
  }

  @XmlRootElement
  private static final class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String bar;

    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ElementAdapter.class)
    public Element baz;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo [bar=" + bar + ", baz=" + jdomElementToString(baz) + "]";
    }

    private String jdomElementToString(Element element) {
        return new XMLOutputter(org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat()).outputString(element);
    }

  }

  private static final class ElementAdapter extends XmlAdapter<org.w3c.dom.Element, Element> {

    @Override
    public Element unmarshal(org.w3c.dom.Element valueToUnmarshal) throws Exception {
        org.jdom.input.DOMBuilder domBuilder = new org.jdom.input.DOMBuilder();
        org.jdom.Element jdomElement = domBuilder.build(valueToUnmarshal);
        return jdomElement;
    }

    @Override
    public org.w3c.dom.Element marshal(Element elementToMarshal) throws Exception {
        org.jdom.Document jdomDocument = new org.jdom.Document((Element) elementToMarshal.detach());
        DOMOutputter domOutputter = new DOMOutputter();
        Document domDocument = domOutputter.output(jdomDocument);
        return domDocument.getDocumentElement();
    }

  }
}
```

The print out from running this is:

```
Foo [bar=bar, baz=<baz>
    <test value="something" />
</baz>]
```

And as you can see what is in the baz tag is assigned "as-is" to the variable in the Foo class.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to debug issues when unmarshalling is to use the `javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler`.

In your case, you can simply add it to your unmarshaller in the main method, e.g.

```
// ...
javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
// ...
```

When you run your test program as-is with the validation handler attached, you'll see something like the following, which is basically telling you you have no Java class corresponding to the `test` element in your XML.

```
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 47; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"test"). Expected elements are (none)]
```

I think you are assuming that your `ElementAdapter` implementation will read & consume the `baz` node and all children as a string. In actuality, I *think* (paging [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan)?) what's happening is that JAXB is doing some pre-walking of the XML tree, during which it sees that you have no model for `test` and subsequently discards `test` and its attribute.

---

To get a feel for what is going on here, first simplify your model and don't worry about the JDOM Element conversion.  Note that I've changed the name of your top level class so it doesn't conflict with the `Test` model class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        String fooString = "<foo bar=\"bar\"><baz><test value=\"something\" /></baz></foo>";
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
                .createContext(new Class<?>[] {Foo.class}, null);
        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
        Foo foo = unmarshaller
                .unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(fooString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))), Foo.class)
                .getValue();

        System.out.println(foo);
    }

    @XmlRootElement()
    public static class Foo {

        @XmlAttribute
        public String bar;

        @XmlElement
        public Baz baz;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "<foo bar=\"" + bar + "\">" + baz.toString() + "</foo>";
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Baz {

        @XmlElement
        public Test test;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "<baz>" + test.toString() + "</baz>";
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Test {
        @XmlAttribute
        public String value;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "<test value=\"" + value + "\"/>";
        }
    }

}
```

This should unmarshal correctly and print `<foo bar="bar"><baz><test value="something"/></baz></foo>`.  Also note that normally you would pass the `JAXBContextFactory` an `ObjectFactory` containing the entire object graph, which would be generated from your XML Schema.  This may be a source of confusion.

---

Now you can add your `XmlAdapter` back, but instead of attempting to convert from `String` to `Element`, convert from `Baz` to `Element`:

```
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        String fooString = "<foo bar=\"bar\"><baz><test value=\"something\" /></baz></foo>";
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
                .createContext(new Class<?>[] {Foo.class}, null);
        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
        Foo foo = unmarshaller
                .unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(fooString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))), Foo.class)
                .getValue();

        System.out.println(foo);
    }

    @XmlRootElement()
    public static class Foo {

        @XmlAttribute
        public String bar;

        @XmlElement
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ElementAdapter.class)
        public Element baz;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "<foo bar=\"" + bar + "\">" + baz.toString() + "</foo>";
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Baz {

        @XmlElement
        public Test test;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "<baz>" + test.toString() + "</baz>";
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Test {
        @XmlAttribute
        public String value;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "<test value=\"" + value + "\"/>";
        }
    }

    public static class ElementAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Baz, Element> {

        @Override
        public Element unmarshal(Baz baz) throws Exception {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            // Note: it is a terrible idea to re-instantiate a context here
            // Use a cached value or a singleton from before
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
                    .createContext(new Class<?>[] {Baz.class}, null);
            javax.xml.bind.Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.marshal(baz, sw);

            Document document = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader(sw.toString()));
            return document.getRootElement();
        }

        @Override
        public Baz marshal(Element v) throws Exception {
            // TODO implement this
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

This should more or less do what you want, though you may have to clean up the `Baz` element some in the adapter (get rid of the XML preamble, etc.) before converting to JDOM. Do note that instantiating another `JAXBContext` in the `ElementAdapter` is probably a terrible idea, and there may be a more efficient way to convert from a JAXB Element to a JDOM Element. This code is just easy to step through in a debugger so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response @justingarrick! The DefaultValidationEventHandler was a great suggestion to help debugging things and something that will be really useful in the future!

One thing that might have been unclear is that baz could contain anything and I don't really control nor care about the content so I actually ended up solving it with a pretty simple XmlAdapter. I'll post that as an answer to help others and for feedback.