# How can I convert object (JAXB) or byte[] (from this object) to `org.w3c.dom.Element`?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I have Java class (JAXB) for example:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.set....
//fill test object
............
```

Now I need convert this object to `org.w3c.dom.Element`

Now I have converter for converte to `byte[]`:

```
public <T> byte[] marshal(T value) {
    try {
      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
      Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
      marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
      marshaller.marshal(value,sw);
      return sw.toString().getBytes();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

And My question: How can I convert `test`  or `byte[]` to `to org.w3c.dom.Element`?

EDIT:

answer the question in the commentary why I need it

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "MessagePrimaryContent")
public class MessagePrimaryContent {

    @XmlAnyElement
    protected Element any;


    public Element getAny() {
        return any;
    }


    public void setAny(Element value) {
        this.any = value;
    }

}
```

I need set My object to `setAny` method. Such protocol and format. I did not invent it

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Usually, you use either jaxb or the dom model.

Comment: @daniu I answered in question

Comment: create new Element from `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()` ?

Comment: @ulab The question is about how to marshal an object as a DOM element. Not about how to simply create a new DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of `@XmlAnyElement Element any` I'd use `@XmlAnyElement(lax = true) Object any`. Then you can simply assign your `test` to `any` and let JAXB marshal it. See this answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9692275/303810

Thus you could avoid pre-marshalling as DOM.

---

Now, to your question.

You basically want to marshal your `test` object as a DOM element. The easiest would be to marshal to a `DOMResult` and then get the element from there.

Something like:

```
  marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
  DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
  marshaller.marshal(value, domResult);
  Node rootNode = domResult.getNode();
  // I'm not quite sure that it's always a Document, but it's easy to figure out
  final Element rootElement = ((Document) rootNode).getDocumentElement();
```